# Run script when I connect something to the line in port?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, hardware, script

I'm connecting my phone to my mac via the line in port to listen to podcasts. I'm using the app LineIn to do this and I was wondering whether there was anyway I could have:

- My audio input be set to line-in
- LineIn launch

when I connect my phone (any device really, I don't use line-in for anything else) via line-in.